# Copy data from Azure blob storage to on Prem shared folder TFS

Tags: tfs, devops, azure-blob-storage

I have files on a azure blob storage. I would like to copy them as part of a build task.

There us the AzureBlob file copy but this seems to copy data to Blog storage and not from.

Would a powershell script be my only choice here?

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't an Azure "blow" storage. Could you please edit your question so we can help you better?

Comment: thanks, i have updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to copy data from/To Azure Blob storage, One of the best tools is [Azcopy](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy) , it currently supports three different OSs: Linux, Windows and MAC OS. If the TFS is unix based, it should work. Powershell or python SDK should also work. if you emphasize on the TFS environment/description you are using I can help with a Python script.